# How to Find out files on condition

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I have lines like this:

```
elastislide.css
handheld1119.css
job-listing1119.css
jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom1119.css
print1119.css
royalslider.min1119.css
staticlayout1119.css
style-imagegallery.css
style.min1119.css
```

I want to find the last 4 characters of the .css filetypes. For instance, I want to find the 1119 and store it in a variable, and these last 4 chars change every month.

Please help.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Bash scripting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any context indicating how you want to use this information, it's hard to post useful code, but the following loops over the matches.

```
find . -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].css' -print |
while read -r file; do
    base=${file%.css}
    prefix=${base%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
    printf "file: %s suffix: %s\n" "$file" "${base#$prefix}"
done
```

This demonstrates the `${var#prefix}` and `${var%suffix}` variable substitutions.

If you have file names containing newlines, the `find | while` construct is not safe. For a production script, you should use something more robust; but for a quick or specialized script, this  should be good enough.